# How do I edit native code for more functionality?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have a WebSocket, and I'm trying to log every message that was sent from that socket. I can't put a dispatchEvent() after the socket.send, so how would I add more code to the existing native code?

I tried saving the native code then adding my code after it:

```
const nativeCode = socket.send;
socket.send = (...args)=>{
    nativeCode(...args);
    console.log(...args);
}
```

Comment: Guess: Try `nativeCode.apply(socket, args)`

Comment: How would I be able to log `...args` with that?

Comment: `I'm trying to log every message that was sent from that socket` What exactly do you mean? Every message that's send _towards_ the socket? Or every message that's _received_ from the socket?

Comment: The same way as you're doing now, you might just need to call the native code with the proper `this`

Comment: Im trying to log every message sent to the server.

Comment: I dont have access to the server, so im trying to log it clientside.

Comment: The answer below gives you pretty much everything you need as long as you can connect to the websocket with it. You can log all messages you send to the websocket and log all messages you receive from it.

Comment: im making an extension so i cant edit the source code.

Comment: You mean you're trying to hook into a websocket that does not belong to you so you can, for whatever reason, monitor the data that's going through it. You should clarify your question and make your intentions clear. Just keep in mind that SO is the place to ask help with _your_ code. It's most definitely not the place ask how to inject into other people's code, as there's very rarely a valid reason to do this, especially on a website.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to your specific code, but here's an example of a websocket class that I usually use when working with websockets. It has all the logging you want:

```js
class MySocket
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.serverHost = window.location.host;
        this.serverPort = 9400;
        this.protocol = 'ws://';
        this.socket = false;
        this.connected = false;
        this.connecting = false;
    }

    connect()
    {
        /* Connection pending */
        if (this.connecting) {
            return;
        }

        /* Websocket secure if needed */
        if (window.location.protocol === 'https:') {
            this.protocol = 'wss://';
        }

        /* Create websocket instance. Bind events */
        const Socket = new WebSocket(this.protocol+this.serverHost+':'+this.serverPort);
        this.setSocketEvents(Socket);
        this.socket = Socket;
    }

    /* Close connection */
    disconnect()
    {
        this.socket.close();
    }

    /* Socket events */
    setSocketEvents(Socket)
    {
        this.connecting = true;

        /* Processed on connection */
        Socket.onopen = () => {
            this.connected = true;
            this.connecting = false;

            console.log('Websocket connection established');
        }

        /* Processed on each new message from the server */
        Socket.onmessage = (Message) => {
            // Log every message from the socket
            console.log(Message);
        }

        /* Processed on disconnect */
        Socket.onclose = () => {
            this.connecting = false;
            this.connected = false;

            console.log('Websocket connection closed');
        }
    }

    sendMessage(msg)
    {
        console.log(msg);
        this.socket.send(msg);
    }
}

// Instantiate
var mySocket = new MySocket();

// Connect
mySocket.connect();

// Sending messages with log
mySocket.sendMessage("foo");

// Sending message without log
mySocket.socket.send("foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using the [`call()` method](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-call/) so I could give it context

```js
const nativeCode = (YOUR NATIVE CODE);
(YOUR NATIVE CODE) = (...args)=>{
    nativeCode.call(this,...args);
    //add what you want below this line
}
```